# How can i split docx' table cell in two cells with python-docx?

Tags: python, split, docx, python-docx, word-table

I searched in python-docx User Guide and find only method merge, but not split.
Also I tried to do something with document.xml but failed.

Comment: think api doesn't support that at the moment, but did you think of inserting a new table into cell?

Comment: You could add the table with as much rows and columns you need and then merge all other cells. Wouldn't that work?